Octave API C++ Ubuntu program emergency stop
I am new to the topic of API.
Can you tell me why the program crashes? What am I doing wrong? I work in Ubuntu. Octave 6.4.0
#include <iostream>
#include <octave/oct.h>
#include <octave/octave.h>
#include <parse.h>
#include <interpreter.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    // Создание матрицы
    Matrix mat(2, 3);
    mat(0, 0) = 1;
    mat(0, 1) = 2;
    mat(0, 2) = 3;
    mat(1, 0) = 4;
    mat(1, 1) = 5;
    mat(1, 2) = 6;

    // Вывод исходной матрицы
    cout << "Исходная матрица:" << endl << mat << endl;

    // Транспонирование матрицы
    octave_value_list in, out;
    in(0) = mat;
    out = octave::feval("transpose", in, 1);

    // Получение транспонированной матрицы из выходного списка значений
    Matrix transposed_mat = out(0).matrix_value();

    // Вывод транспонированной матрицы
    cout << "Транспонированная матрица:" << endl << transposed_mat << endl;

    return 0;
}

Here's my compilation:
g++ -o 2 2.cpp -I/usr/include/octave-6.4.0 -I/usr/include/octave-6.4.0/octave -I/usr/include/octave-6.4.0/octave/interpreter -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/octave-6.4.0/octave -loctave -loctinterp -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/octave/6.4.0 -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/octave/6.4.0 -Wl,--no-as-needed -loctave -loctinterp

It's very difficult to understand the topic of API without manuals(didn't find them), but so far I've only tried to write a solution to a system of linear equations(got it and it works).
If there is something wrong with compilation, please advise.

Please provide the output this program produces. Also, [edit] your question so the code is indented/formatted consistently, please.

Yeah, lol, this is the least useful documentation ever put online! https://docs.octave.org/doxygen/3.8/d6/db6/classoctave__value__list.html — Honesly, they could just as well not post anything.

My guess is that the exception happens in this line:
octave_value_list in;
in(0) = mat;

An octave_value_list is very much like a std::vector<>. Here you declare an empty list, then you attempt to assign something to the first element, which doesn’t exist.
You can fix this code in one of three ways:
octave_value_list in(1); // declare it with the right size
in(0) = mat;

or
octave_value_list in;
in.append(mat); // append to the list

or
octave_value_list in(mat); // put the array in the list upon creation


The conclusion is as follows:
The original matrix is:
1 2 3
4 5 6
Emergency stop (memory image dumped to disk)
